# Get cloudant (couchDB) database documents by passing a list of keys

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant

So I have searched a lot but I don't currently have a solution for this. Following is the query to get documents from cloudant (couchDB) database based on multiple keys ("key-1" and "key-2").

```
db.getViewRequestBuilder("example", "foo").newRequest(Key.Type
                        .STRING,
                Object.class).includeDocs(false).keys("key-1", "key-2").build()
                .getResponse().getDocs();
```

This doesn't seem to work if I just pass a list of keys. I have a `List 
<String> keys` that I would like to pass here and get all the docs. Does anyone know the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this finally:

```
return db.getAllDocsRequestBuilder()
            .includeDocs(true)
            .keys(keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]))
            .build().getResponse().getDocsAs(Object.class);
```

Hope it helps others as well.